# How to update datatable rows without using a dict

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash app, which accepts a csv file, and from that, updates a datatable object (from the `dash_table_experiments` library). Currently, I read in the CSV, decode it and eventually convert it to a dict so that I can update the rows of the datatable.

For larger files however, the `to_dict()` operation is too slow, is there an another way to pass the data from the CSV file to the datatable and update the rows? For example, it would be great if there were some way I could update the rows using a json style string instead, as this is much faster to compute.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
@app.callback(Output('uploaded-data', 'hidden'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_hidden_datatable(contents, filename):
    global base_data
    if contents is not None:
        content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        try:
            if '.csv' in filename:
                # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
                df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), low_memory = False)
            elif '.xls' in filename:
                # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
                df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return base_data.to_dict('r')
        for column in df.select_dtypes(include=[bool]):
            df[column] = df[column].map({True: 'true', False: 'false'})
        return df.to_dict('r')

    return base_data.to_dict('r')

# Updates the rows of the main datatable when the hidden uploaded-data value is updated
@app.callback(Output('datatable', 'rows'),
              [Input('uploaded-data', 'hidden')])
def update_datatable(hidden):
    return hidden
```

There is a reason that I am first storing the data in a hidden div, but it is too complicated to discuss here.

Comment: Are you sure that the question relates to Dash, not to the database update? AFAIK, Dash doesn't handle DB connections itself, but in the code presented I see no manipulations with a database. Could you provide additional details related to the problem? For sure, you can update without using dict, but the exact answer depends on those details.

Comment: Hey so I'm not using a DB. I'm just reading in the data through my `update_hidden_datatable` function, and then storing the data as the 'hidden' value of a hidden div (which is initialised as `html.Div(id='uploaded-data', hidden=base_df.to_dict('records')`). Following any changes to the hidden div's 'hidden' field, the datatable updates its records with that value. Does that help?